# Assembly How to loop character in user-defined counter

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dosbox

i'm a beginner in assembly8086 (Using DosBOX).
We have an assignment to produce the following:
[See this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi03x.png)

I tried doing it and this is my sample code.

```
mov ah,9
lea dx,[100]    // Enter a character: $
int 21h
mov ah,1
int 21h
mov bl,al
mov ah,9
lea dx,[120]    // Enter a number: $
int 21h
mov ah,1
int 21h
mov [si],al
mov cx,[si]
mov ah,2        // 14e
mov dl,bl
int 21h
inc cx
loop 14e
```

The problem occurs when i inputted a number after Enter a number.
It displays the correct character i inputted but it doesn't stop to the required number of loop. It simply spams the character infinitely.

EDIT::::
Its now displaying correctly. I just want to know how to print the "Enter a number: $" on the next line.

Because this is what happens:
Enter a character: **d**Enter a number: **4**dddd

Here is the edited code:

```
mov ah,9
lea dx,[100]    // Enter a character: $
int 21h
mov ah,1
int 21h
mov bl,al
mov ah,9
lea dx,[120]    // Enter a number: $
int 21h
mov ah,1
int 21h
sub al,30
mov cl,al
xor ch,ch
mov ah,2        // 150
mov dl,bl
int 21h
loop 150
```

Comment: Remember that the DOS interrupt reads a *character* from the terminal. If you read `4` as your input, you aren't getting the number 4. You are getting the ASCII representation of 4, which is 34h. Ignoring checking for valid input for a moment, you could just subtract 30h from `al` to get the number. I'm also curious as to why you are doing `mov [si], al` then `mov cx, [si]`. Why not just `mov cl, al` and `xor ch, ch`? Or you could similarly do `xor ah, ah` then `mov cx, ax`. It's unclear from your code where `si` points to in memory.

Comment: @khnkhymkh Please edit your question to include the updated code.  Do not link to external paste services.  Also make sure to not remove the original code from the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `loop`instruction decreases `CX`, while you *inside* the loop *increase* `CX`.

So the value of `CX` will never reach zero and cause the `loop` instruction to end.

Finding this out should have been very easy if you stepped through the code instruction by instruction in a debugger, watching the value of `CX`.

Comment: You forgot to say that avoiding the `loop` instruction entirely is the right way to go if you want to use CL/CH/CX inside the loop, or to count upwards.  `cmp CX, 9` / `jbe` might be what they want.  `loop` is one of those complex CISC instructions that the're no reason to teach.  Just use conditional branches for loops, because you have to understand them anyway to do conditions.  So your basic down-counting loop boilerplate is `dec cx / jnz` which is identical to `loop` except it writes flags.

Answer (score 0):

> Enter a character: **d**Enter a number: **4**dddd

After solving the original problem(s) you expressed an additional issue.

> I just want to know how to print the "Enter a number: $" on the next line.

You do this by outputting a carriage return (13) / linefeed (10) pair.

```
mov ah,9
lea dx,[100]    // Enter a character: $
int 21h
mov ah,1
int 21h
mov bl,al

mov dl, 13     ; Carriage return
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
mov dl, 10     ; Linefeed
mov ah, 02h
int 21h

mov ah,9
lea dx,[120]    // Enter a number: $
int 21h
...
```